# Bootstrap Popover, show one hide others

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have many rows in a table and whenever one row is clicked, i will have a popover that appears in one of the  i created in that row.

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', ".job-row", function() {
   $('.click-more-info').popover('hide');
   $(this).find('.click-more-info').popover('show');
 });
});
```

`.job-row` is the TR for every row in my table.

`.click-more-info` is what I need to show.

Everything runs well, the popover shows when I click the row, and another shows when I click another new row with the previous one disappearing.

However, when I click back to any of the rows I've clicked before, it will show and disappear immediately.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the popover before calling him again:

```
$(element).popover("destroy").popover({
        html: true,
        placement: "top",
        title: "title",
        content: function () {
            return $('.wrapper-html-content').html();
        }
    }).popover("show");
```

here i just create the popover with a html content.

try this and see if works.